# How to limit the display size of a table populated from a database?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, postgresql

Im using React, Node, Express, Postgres to populate a table with data taken from postgres. The problem is the table is very long, so ideally I want to only display 5 rows and add a scroll bar to the table.

My table in React:

```
return <Fragment>

        <div id="ListContactTable">
        <table className="table mt-5" id="ListContactTable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Supplier Name</th>
                    <th>Contact Name</th>
                    <th>Job Title</th>
                    <th>Edit Entry</th>
                    <th>Delete Entry</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {contacts.map(contact => (
                    <tr key={contact.scontact_id}>
                        <td>{contact.supplier_name}</td>
                        <td>{contact.scontact_name}</td>
                        <td>{contact.scontact_title}</td>
                        <td><EditContact contact={contact} getContact={getContact}/></td>
                        <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=> deleteContact(contact.scontact_id)}>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                ))}           
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </Fragment>
```

I have tried using css on both the table and the div it's placed in to try and limit the table height, but it didn't work out:

```
.modal-body{
  overflow-y:scroll; 
  max-height: 300px;
}
#ListContactTable{
  height: 300px;
}
.modal-dialog {
  width: 600px;
}
.modal-footer {
  border-top: 0 none;
}
```

So how would I go about limiting the display size of the table, and adding a scrollbar to it?

**Solution**
Just had to add this to my table:

```
table 
{
    table-layout:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Give it a width and height to the td's of table and it will work

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way is to change your mapping code to:

```
{contacts.slice(0,5).map(contact => (
                    <tr key={contact.scontact_id}>
                        <td>{contact.supplier_name}</td>
                        <td>{contact.scontact_name}</td>
                        <td>{contact.scontact_title}</td>
                        <td><EditContact contact={contact} getContact={getContact}/></td>
                        <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={()=> deleteContact(contact.scontact_id)}>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
```

another way is goto your node backend and set limit for your GET controller.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, could you please explain what slice(0,5) does here?

Comment: The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array into a new array object selected from start to end (end not included) where start and end represent the index of items in that array. The original array will not be modified.Just check the example code at mdn:[link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice);If you think my answer is useful please click the accept button @Vanillaice